# Windows 8 som click

Tags: delphi-7, windows-8

Ao usar o componente `TWebBrowser` (que é do Internet Explorer) rodando na plataforma Win7, cada vez que se navega é feito um barulho chato de *click*.

Até agora não vi nada em fóruns sobre esse comportamento no Windows 8, essa pergunta e resposta ajudará muitas pessoas.

Então, um aplicativo feito em Delphi 7 usando o componente `TWebBrowser`(IE) ao rodar no Windows 8 continua com o barulho de *click* quando está navegando?

Comment: Olá Renan tudo bom cara? Então velho eu não sei pois acredito que está bem clara mas de qualquer forma vou tentar editar e corrigir o português rsrs

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações Maycon, você pode [reverter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/59179/revisions) caso não apresente melhorias.

Comment: Fico Melhor, Obrigado Renan gostei!

Comment: Acredito que continua sim, não haveria motivo para não ter.

Answer (score 0):

```
const
  SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS = $00000002;
  FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS = 21;

function CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FeatureEntry: DWORD;
  dwFlags: DWORD; fEnable: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'urlmon.dll';
```

Basta adicionar a seguinte linha no Form Load

```
CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, True);
```

Boa sorte nesses testadores rsrsrsrs.